# iOS: Fire method at gradually increasing speed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, gamekit

My game plays a ticking clock sound every second. I would like the sound to slowly speed up throughout the game. My initial thought was to use an NSTimer and update the speed when the method fires, like this:

```
static float soundDelay = 1.0;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:clickClackDelay
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(playSound)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];

- (void)playSound {
    soundDelay -= 0.1;
    NSLog(@"Play sound");
}
```

This didn't work, and it seems like NSTimer isn't really meant to be used that way. Any other suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible for what you're spesifically working on, but how about recurrsion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by calling the `playSound` method from itself.
You can do it in the following way.

```
- (void)playSound
{
   static float soundDelay = 1.0;
   if([timer isValid])
   {
     [timer invalidate];
     timer = nil;
   }
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:clickClackDelay
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(playSound)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:NO];
    soundDelay -= 0.1;
    if(soundDelay <=0)   //when sound delay is zero invalidate timer
    {
       [timer invalidate];
       timer = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"Play sound");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same timer to call `-playSound` repeatedly. Instead, use the timer to call the method once, and subsequently create a new timer with a shorter delay. For example, you could create the timer in `-playSound` itself, so that a new timer is created each time `-playSound` is called.

Comment: You were first with the right answer. It would seem no code means no lovin'. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should re-schedule another timer for this purpose.

```
- (void)playSound {
    static float soundDelay = 1.0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:soundDelay
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(playSound)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:NO];
    if (soundDelay > 0.1) {
        soundDelay -= 0.1;
    }
    NSLog(@"Play sound");
}
```

p.s. you may want to add a terminating condition.